# How to access to NexusDB from Java

Tags: java, nexusdb

I want to access to NexusDB V3 with Java.
So I have a Java project with many files that connects to the database. Can anyone tell me if it is possible to use a Java class file for connecting to the database.
I've tried JDBC connector and the ODBC connector but nothing is working.
I have read about a bridge between them but I don't know how to make it so please help.

```
public class dbConnect {
    public static void connect(){
        Connection conn;
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;

        String sql;
        conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_oopproject";
        try{
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","12345");

            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            sql = "Select * from user_account";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you define `driver` for `Class.forName(driver)`??

Comment: You have to use ODBC Bridge but this has been deprecated and removed from Java 8 http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0107.html

Answer (score 1):

first off, your url contains "mysql", are you sure that will work for the jdbc bridge to connect to NexusDB?

Comment: And ODBC Bridge has been deprecated so I would avoid, also in Java 8 this has been removed see here http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0107.html

Comment: don't really know i m just trying